# pg_close must to wait query end

Tags: php, postgresql, asynchronous, postgresql-9.4, amazon-aurora

I'm making a function that register a big CSV data file so i am searching the ways that can send asynchronous query to postgre sql server and receive query result later.
I tried to use pg_send_query to send SQL(that take time to query) like bellow.

SQL

```
 $sql   = SELECT * FROM BATCH_WORK_TBL WHERE COPR_ID='99999999test';
```

PHP script

```
//-----------------------------------------------
// DB Conntect
//-----------------------------------------------
$conn = pg_connect('user=username dbname=databasename');

//-----------------------------------------------
// Send asynchronous query
//-----------------------------------------------
$sql = " SELECT * FROM BATCH_WORK_TBL WHERE COPR_ID='99999999test' ";
if (!pg_connection_busy( $conn  )) {
    $res = pg_send_query($conn , $sql ); // pg_send_query return result(true/flase) without wait results
}
pg_close($conn); // pg_close wait until it query return result
```

however, when i close connection,pg_close() wait for a long time until query return query result so finally my php script take a long time run.

Any body if has experience on asynchronous query on posgres sql with php, could you pls help me in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That cannot work. *Something* has to keep the database connection open so that the query result can be received.

You can either keep the connection open, do some other work and come back later to check on the connection, or you write a co-process that does that waiting for you (and has the database connection).

Comment: Thank @Laurenz Albe for your answer.

Comment: Sorry, can i ask 1 question?  
Oracle has a kind of cron built-in called DBMS_JOB.  You can use it to run SQL or stored procedures at certain times of day, etc.
Does postgreSQL offer anything similar? (Dont use cron)

Comment: There is no built-in scheduler. You can use the operating system's scheduler or an extension like `pg_cron`.